# If statement in SQL issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Access to run queries on a database called dbo_item. It contains a column called itm_class that contains numbers 1-100. It also contains columns called itm_len, itm_wid, itm_hgt, pal_len, pal_wid, pal_hgt. Depending on the item class number, I need it to calculate the volume either by item dimensions or by pallet dimensions. I have tried a few different things, but am not really sure how to get the If statement to work. Any help would be appreciated.

I.E. If itm_class equals 1,5,22,45,67,89,97,98,99,100 then volume is (itm_len * itm_wid * itm_hgt) and for all other itm_class numbers, volume is (pal_len * pal_wid * pal_hgt). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Search for CASE statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `iif` condition for this.

```
IIF(itm_class in (1,5,22,45,67,89,97,98,99,100), itm_len * itm_wid * itm_hgt, pal_len * pal_wid * pal_hgt)
```

It works like , If condition(1st argument) is True, select the first value (2nd argument) or else select the other (3rd argument)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect. I was just a little messed up on the context.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are doing this statement in visual-basic or if you are doing it at a database level (function/stored procedure) or if you are doing it with the query. The simplest way would be with a `case when`  statement in your query such as:

```
select case when itm_class in (1,2,3,4) then (itm_len * itm_wid * itm_hgt)
   when itm_class in (5,6,7,8) then (itm_len * itm_wid) 
   else (itm_len * itm_wid) end volume_calculation
from some_table
```